# i want to find out the names of employee whose sallery is greater than 15000

Tags: class

the question create a class name employe which has employe details of three people and I want to find out how much people have sallery greater than 15000

```
class employe:
    def __init__ (self,i,name,sallery):
    self.i=i
    self.name=name
    self.sallery=sallery
a=employe(1,"vinod",10000)
b=employe(2,"vikas",20000)
c=employe(3,"kailash",30000)
def sort(a,b,c):
    pay=[]
    if a.sallery>15000:
        pay.append(a.name)
    elif b.sallery>15000:
        pay.append(b.name)
    elif c.sallery>15000:
        pay.append(c.name)
    return pay
sort(a,b,c)
```

according to me the output should be vikas and kailash but it is only shows vikas the kailash is not seen the code is running till elif b.sallery>15000:
pay.append(b.name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your `elif` conditions for single `if conditions` that will do the trick. 
That's because of the behavior of `if-elif-else` structure, If you look at it carefully, you'll find out that when you're calling your function, in that call, it first passes through the first if `if a.sallery > 15000` which is not true, then it goes through the second condition `if b.sallery > 15000` which is true, then `vikas` gets inserted into the array and that's it, the code doesn't need to go through the third condition, because the previous one already returned true.

Hope I have explained myself well.

Comment: yes you said right I corrected it by myself and felled happy to debug it by my own and thank you for your answer it was my first question on stackoverflow and you answer really quick